# What should users do to move questions to the more appropriate site?

Tags: discussion, moving-questions, sffaq, belongs-on

I don't see this question clearly asked and answered anywhere, it's certainly not in the ServerFault FAQ where I was trying to find it.

From reading some of the stuff on meta, it seems that:

- the correct way to deal with a question on ServerFault that should be on SuperUser is to flag it for moderator attention with a note that the question belongs elsewhere.
- the wrong thing to do is to slap on a "belongs-on-superuser" tag.

Is that about right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct.

- If you have enough reputation, vote "belongs on xxxxx". You can also flag the question.
- If you do not have 3k+ rep, you can flag the question.
- Never use the "belongs on xxxxx" tag on any question. This has been discussed a few times and the conclusion is to not use those tags on any of the sites.